# RestSharp for .Net Framework how to make a RestRequest with Direct connection (without Proxy)

Tags: proxy, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp 106.6.10.
The need is to make a request skipping the default Proxy, as I thought:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://<my ip>");
client.Proxy = null; //=> it is null by default, in reality
...
var request = new RestRequest("streams/..."
```

But in reality the Default Proxy is used, and the request is rejected by the Proxy for authentication issue.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

1) `client.Proxy = null;` => not working (as already said)

2) `client.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();` => OK but deprecated

3) `client.Proxy = new WebProxy();` => works fine

Hoping it could be of any help to others, thanks everybody.

Lorenzo